# Drupal Views - how to show a sporting club record holders all at once?

Tags: views

I have a database of football games like this:

date, opponent, venue, our score, their score etc

Id like to have a view that extracts things like

- highest winning margin
- highest score
- most goals etc

and displays them all at the same time

The only way I can think of doing this is to have a view with lots of attachments- one for each statistic.  Is there a better way? (I have to maintain this myself so no php)

Comment: Views has an aggregate function which you need to use. For even greater control of aggregation install [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator). To learn about aggregation visit [Taming the Beast: Learn Views with NodeOne](http://nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) Chapters 28 - 30

Comment: You may also find this module useful: [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc)